# page title does not appear on stumbleupon

Tags: html, stumbleupon

When i added a link to stumbleupon, it does not show up the title of the page but just shows the raw link . I searched around it said that it reads from title attribute in page . But i have title attribute in the page html showing the title . So what is wrong in my blog config that the page title does not appear . Appreaciate your help .

http://agose.in/60/adf-tutorial-create-first-web-application-oracle-adf-2/